# /dev/sda Currently unreadable (pending) sectors alert but smartclt shows everything as 0

Tags: linux, debian, hard-drive, ssd, smartctl

I already read the similar questions but mine seems to tell a different story or the answers there don't work for me.

- [SMART error (CurrentPendingSector) detected on host](https://serverfault.com/questions/898170/smart-error-currentpendingsector-detected-on-host)
- [Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors](https://serverfault.com/questions/851441/device-dev-sda-sat-1-currently-unreadable-pending-sectors)
- [Current Pending Sector S.M.A.R.T. attribute](https://serverfault.com/questions/280815/current-pending-sector-s-m-a-r-t-attribute)
- [smartctl reports Current Pending Sectors as 2, but a long test doesn't find any errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/472269/smartctl-reports-current-pending-sectors-as-2-but-a-long-test-doesnt-find-any)

I'm getting the following email/alert from my server:

> The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:
>
> Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
>
> Device info:
> CT4000MX500SSD1, S/N:2304E6A3D318, WWN:5-00a075-1e6a3d318, FW:M3CR045, 4.00 TB

I ran a few of the recommended diagnostic commands but they don't show any error/issue.

- `Current_Pending_Sector` shows 0 and show does `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`
- long test shows no errors

**So I'm very confused as to what could be wrong?**

## `sudo smartctl -q noserial -a /dev/sda`:

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.0-13-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     CT4000MX500SSD1
Serial Number:    2304E6A3D318
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1e6a3d318
Firmware Version: M3CR045
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available
Device is:        Not in smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Nov  1 08:10:38 2023 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  30) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0031) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5040
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       89
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
180 Unused_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       204
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   076   058   000    Old_age   Always       -       24 (Min/Max 0/42)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       22881573326
247 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       218603247
248 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       121436969

SMART Error Log Version: 1
Invalid Error Log index = 0x09 (T13/1321D rev 1c Section 8.41.6.8.2.2 gives valid range from 1 to 5)

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4605         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2331         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2319         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2295         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2271         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2246         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2222         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2198         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2173         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2172         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2149         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2125         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2100         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2076         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2052         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2027         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2003         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1979         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1955         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1930         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1906         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

## `sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda`:

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.1.0-13-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      4605         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2331         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2319         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2295         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2271         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2246         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2222         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2198         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2173         -
#10  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2172         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2149         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2125         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2100         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2076         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2052         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2027         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2003         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1979         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1955         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1930         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1906         -
```